# How to use numpy mgrid or meshgrid for that simple task

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

I have a somewhat simple thing to do but still I don't success with numpy mgrid&meshgrid.
I have a numpy vector of 100 elements:

```
[0,0,0...0]
```

and I would like to create a `1000x100` numpy array like that, each time increasing one of the vector values by `0.1`, switching to the next vector values when reaching `1.0`.
So, the first iterations should give me:

```
[0.1 0 0..0]
[0.2 0 0..0]
.
.
[0.9 0 0..0]
[1.0 0 0..0]
```

from now I should iterate on the second vector number,keeping the previous values:

```
[1.0 0.1 0 0..0]
[1.0 0.2 0 0..0]
[1.0 0.3 0 0..0]
```

And so on. The final matrix should be something like 1000x100, but I don't need to get all the values together in one big numpy array - it would be enough to iterate and produce at each iteration the corrisponding vector.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `initialization` and [`np.maximum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) -

```
def create_stepped_cols(n): # n = number of cols
    out = np.zeros((n,10,n))
    r = np.linspace(0.1,1.0,10)
    d = np.arange(n)
    out[d,:,d] = r
    out.shape = (-1,n)
    np.maximum.accumulate(out, axis=0, out = out)
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [140]: create_stepped_cols(3)
Out[140]: 
array([[ 0.1,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.2,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.3,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.4,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.5,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.6,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.7,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.8,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.9,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.1,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.2,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.3,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.4,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.5,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.6,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.7,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.8,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.9,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.1],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.2],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.3],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.4],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.5],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.6],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.7],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.8],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.9],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ]])

In [141]: create_stepped_cols(100).shape
Out[141]: (1000, 100)
```